# Jibx Error running binding compiler in eclipse oxygen maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, jibx

I am new to jibx world i have generated the binding.xml and .java classes from CMD using **mvn generate-sources** phase everything work's fine even binding is happening(Able to convert XML to Object). Issue is when building the project eclipse Is **overriding the .class files**. later I installed jibx compiler as eclipse plugin but it through's the error.

[image]

Here is how my pom.xml looks like.

[image]

I tried bcel - 6.0 SNAPSHOT and 6.1 and all doesn't work at all. Please help on this how do I make sure eclipse doesn't override jibx .class files.
**NOTE: Using JDK 8**